# My Azure Skype Bot in Preview Mode is Not Responding On Skype

Tags: azure, skype

My Skype bot is not responding. It is NOT published, and it is in PREVIEW mode with 100 allowed contacts.

It works from Azure test in web chat. I added it as a contact from the Azure page. I created an HTML page using the chat bot and it works through HTML iframes.

I contacted Microsoft Support, and they told me to try web.skype.com. My skype bot works from here as well.

However, when I use Skype from windows, my bot does not respond.

Answer (score 0):

When i tried it from web.skype.com, I had the idea that although I added the bot as a contact, it wasn't actually a contact.

From my phone, I added my bot as a contact. After I added the bot as a contact on my phone, it started working on windows.